# pandas left join on one key and one column value inside other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, left-join

If I have 2 panda df, I want to let A left join B on 2 conditions, 1) A.id = B.id 2) A.x in B.x_set. Can anyone help me on this? :

A:

```
id  x
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

B:

```
id  x_set   detail
1   a,b,c   x
1   d       y
2   a,c     z
2   d       m
2   b       n
3   a       i
3   b,c     j
```

The final table should be like this:

```
id  x   detail
1   a   x
2   b   n
3   c   j
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Could you post how your final dataframe would look like?

Comment: @JuanC thanks, I just updated, plz help to take a look.

Comment: Please can you copy and paste text rather than images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using `pandas==0.25`, you can:

1. Transform the values to list
2. *Explode* the list into new rows
3. Merge back with A using `pd.merge`

```py
B['x_set'] = B['x_set'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
B = B.explode('x_set')

A.merge(B, left_on=['id','x'], right_on=['id','x_set'])

Out[11]: 
   id  x x_set detail
0   1  a     a      x
1   2  b     b      n
2   3  c     c      j
```

If `pandas<0.25`:

1. Transform the values to list
2. Get flatten list of x
3. Create a new dataframe with the new list
4. Pass the `id` and `detail` using `pd.Series.repeat`
5. Merge with A (we can use the same keys here)

```py
B['x_set'] = B['x_set'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))

len_set = B['x_set'].apply(len).values

values = B['x_set'].values.flatten().tolist()
flat_results = [item for sublist in values for item in sublist]

new_B = pd.DataFrame(flat_results, columns=['x'])

new_B['id'] = B['id'].repeat(len_set).values
new_B['detail'] = B['detail'].repeat(len_set).values

A.merge(new_B, on=['id','x'])
Out[32]: 
   id  x detail
0   1  a      x
1   2  b      n
2   3  c      j
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but if I have error='DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'. I don't have pySpark on my machine.

Comment: That is actually just the latest version of `pandas`. I posted a second solution for older versions, check if that works?